# Use RequestInterceptor to intercept all request in Spring cloud gateway?

Tags: spring, cloud, spring-cloud, gateway, spring-cloud-gateway

I have custom RequestInterceptor that implements org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor. Is there a way to configure spring cloud gateway to intercept all the requests at this interceptor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No. Gateway does not use any Apache components

Comment: @spencergibb So the only way to intercept the requests is through GlobalFilters?

Comment: GlobalFilters apply to all routes, GatewayFilters only apply to the route for which they are configured.

Comment: Thank you @spencergibb